# Side by side Divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to keep Div 1,2 and 3 on left side in Bootstrap(or without bootstrap) , but when I add text to div1 or height increases , div3 goes to right side(I want to keep div3 on the left side).

This is a [bootply example.](http://www.bootply.com/6YZ8MdmXaA)

[image]

Text3(div3) should be on the left side.

I also added `float:left;` to divs but it didn't work.

How can I fix this?

HTML

```
<div class="container">      
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
      Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
      Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
      Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
       Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
    </div>      
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .
      Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .
      Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .
    </div>      
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .
      Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .
      Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
}
.col-md-6{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use Bootstrap's `.row` class like this:

**Bootply - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/9L2vRjaJDK)**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
          Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
          Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
          Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
           Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .
          Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .
          Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .
        </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .
          Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .
          Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add css rule `clear:both` to the last div or change your col-* classes to fit within bootstrap grid system

Answer (score 0):

Use (change `md` to whatever the size is):

```
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
```

Remove `visible-md-block` if you would like to break on every size. (If that's what you want to do, then perhaps you should create a new row instead.)

Also don't forget to add `.row` to your container.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/v2371qza/3/embedded/result/

Quoting from [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
    <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using bootstrap you can add `.clear` class for the last `.col-md-6` or you can add a div before the last `.col-md-6`

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-6">
          Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
          Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
          Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
          Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
           Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .
          Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .
          Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-6" id ="left">
          Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .
          Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .
          Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .
        </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
}
#left {
  clear:left;
}
```

Clears the left side of the div that has to appear on the left.

Comment: you can simply use class="row" from bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If you dont wanted to Use Bootstrap, Here is the fiddle how to achieve Goal 
[Without Bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/RohitHarish/2a86do9m/1/). Try to use `Display:inline-block` instead of `float` and you can ignore `margin` between divs i have use in jsfiddle example

Queries are most welcomed

Answer (score 0):

You can col-sm-12

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
      Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
      Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
      Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
       Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .Text 1 .
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .
      Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .
      Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .Text 2 .
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .
      Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .
      Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .Text 3 .
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this was what your where looking for I gave you the HTML Mark-UP & The CSS. If you have further questions please feel free to ask.

```
/*YOUR CSS MARK UP*/
#left-container{
width:400px;/*this width can be whatever you want*/
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
#one{
width:200px;
height:300px;
background-color:#0CF;
}
#two{
width:200px;
height:300px;
background-color:#C69;
}
#three{
width:200px;
height:300px;
background-color:#C96;
}
<!--Your HTML MARK UP BELOW-->
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="left-container">
<div id="one">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is          some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
<div id="two">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is    some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
<div id="three">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP is using Bootstrap.

Comment: I want to keep Div 1,2 and 3 on left side in Bootstrap(or without bootstrap)